# Range filter does not support format

Tags: elasticsearch

I got an unknown issue with elasticsearch, and can't solve it.

Here's my query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": []
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "gte": "14/04/1915",
                "lte": "10/05/1915",
                "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query does not work well.
Here's the result of /_validate/query?explain

```
"index": "dev",
"valid": false,
"error": "org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [dev] [range] filter does not support [format]"
```

Do you why it does not work ?

I can't manage to find the answer anywhere on the Inet

Comment: have you looked [official elastic search date range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html)

Comment: Sur I did. And the official doc says you can use "format" inside a range filter

Comment: @AndreiStefan ES version : 1.4.5

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7821 added in 1.5.0. That's why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: So, upgrade and try again ;-).

Comment: OK guys, I was so dumb to not look at the ES version. It's working now. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndreiStefan, please put your comment as an answer. I had the very same problem just now and you solved it for me.

Comment: @Kay I'm glad it helped you. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because of this issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7821 which has been added in 1.5.0. In your case, the solution is to upgrade.